# Symfony clear Post data

Tags: post, symfony-1.4

I need to clear the POST data (`$request->getPostParameter()`) so that if the user refreshes the page the data does not get resubmitted. How do I do this in symfony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule in symfony is to redirect (not forward) in a controller that accepts post data, and presumably writes to the database. You can this behaviour in the generated action.class.php when using generate-module

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. Aside from alternative methods, is it possible to do what I wanted: clear post data?

Comment: You can experiment with `offsetUnset` or the parameter holder object with `getParameterHolder()`, but no, there is no direct way to clear out the post request parameters

Answer (score 0):

I needed to reload previously loaded page without redirect, because the request was sent by ajax... so I processed the form and then just changed method from POST to GET, which prevent form resubmittion, and then forwarded request to another controller. Here is the code:

```
$request = $this->get('request');
$request->setMethod('GET');
$response = $this->forward($controller, $params);
return $response;
```